# How can I render only a region in a controller?

Tags: theming

I'm looking to have a page on /templates/header which only renders what there is in the *header* region of the theme. I am using the following code for a custom controller.

```php
namespace Drupal\wco_drupal_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Templates controller.
**/
class TemplatesController extends ControllerBase {

  public function header() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'wco_templates_header',
    ];
  }

}
```

In the *wco_drupal_module.module* file, I am using the following code.

```php
function wco_drupal_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'wco_templates_header' => [
      'render element' => 'requirements',
      'template' => 'region--header',
      'path' => $theme . '/templates/layout',
    ],
  ];
}
```

The *region-header.html.twig* template file contains the following code.

```
<h1>tasty test</h1>
{% if content %}
  <div class='flex-column region-headerW' >
    <div class='region region-header maxwidth' >
      {{ content }}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

This renders *something*, but there are two problems:

- The content is missing, so I only see *tasty test*.
- This is all rendered inside the generic layout; rather than just showing the header, I'm showing a whole page with header, footer, and all the regions.

I want to avoid that, and only display a single region (*header*) on a path. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to generate a block and not a page if I understand correctly? But in this case you won't have a path. Do you want a path with only the contents of your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display a single region, header, on a path:

1. create path :
   for this either can add node page with specific path or add custom controller
2. View the path let say /header
3. Then override the page template with specific path as displayed in the inspect provided by theme suggestion
   for eg override file name: page--testing--abc.html.twig
   [Reference link for enable theme suggestion](https://toswebdeveloper.com/blog/how-enable-theme-suggestions-drupal-9)
4. Then open the override file in editor & keep the required region:
   like in my scenario:  {{ page.header }}

Note: Make sure in the backend if you added additional block in the same region(header) then that 'll start appearing so hide other blocks for this particular page
or either add new region and add that region in override template , add header block of site from backend in newly added region

Comment: Fantastic, super simple. thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's pretty easy approach, handling things at theme level  your welcome ;)